Unable to screen record my game while playing online on chess.com mobile app on Galaxy S23 Ultra
When I try to screen record my game while playing online on chess.com mobile app it does not record the screen.  When I checked the recording it shows only black screen.  I am using Galaxy S23 Ultra's native Screen Recorder for recording.  Any solution ?

It is because the app(chess) restricted itself to screen recording.

If you are not able to screen record some apps, it's because the app does not allow it due to security measures. In this case, there is nothing you can do. However, you can try using a third-party screen recorder.
